# ASP.NET MVC DataViewModel Problem no insert and edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

using the code DataViewModel with one form for create and edit with partial view , in the code below In the create**I am not able to enter the values to the database**,In the edit Mode **I am not able to display the value as well in the textboxes for edit**(The record is created but no form value is going to the database).

```
 public  class OrganizationGroupFormViewModel
{

// Properties
    public OrganizationGroup OrganizationGroup { get; private set; }

    public OrganizationGroupFormViewModel(OrganizationGroup organizationGroup)
    {
        OrganizationGroup = organizationGroup;

    }
```

}

```
public class OrganizationGroupsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /OrganizationGroups/
    OrganizationGroupsRepository OrganizationGroupRepository = new OrganizationGroupsRepository();
    OrganizationUsersDataContext _db = new OrganizationUsersDataContext();

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        try
        {
            OrganizationGroup OrgGroup = new OrganizationGroup()  {
                int_CreatedBy=1,
                dtm_CreatedDate=DateTime.Now

            };

            return View(new OrganizationGroupFormViewModel(OrgGroup));
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }

          }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(OrganizationGroup OrgGroup)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            OrgGroup.int_CreatedBy = 1;
            OrgGroup.dtm_CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            OrganizationGroupRepository.Add(OrgGroup);
            OrganizationGroupRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = OrganizationGroupRepository.int_OrganizationGroupId });

        }
        return View(new OrganizationGroupFormViewModel(OrgGroup));
    }

    //
    // GET: /OrganizationGroups/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var OrgGroup = _db.OrganizationGroups.First(m => m.int_OrganizationGroupId == id);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                OrgGroup.int_ModifiedBy = 1;
                OrgGroup.dtm_ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;


            }
            return View(new OrganizationGroupFormViewModel(OrgGroup));
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    //
    // POST: /OrganizationGroups/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {

            var OrgGroup = _db.OrganizationGroups.First(m => m.int_OrganizationGroupId == id);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                OrgGroup.int_ModifiedBy = 1;
                OrgGroup.dtm_ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                TryUpdateModel(OrgGroup);
                OrganizationGroupRepository.Save();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = OrgGroup.int_OrganizationGroupId });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Create View;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Egovst.Controllers.OrganizationGroupFormViewModel>" %>
```

Create Organization Group

```
<h2>Create</h2>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

<div>
    <% Html.RenderPartial("OrganizationGroup"); %>
</div>
```

Organization Group User Control

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Egovst.Controllers.OrganizationGroupFormViewModel>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>


        <div class="editor-label">
            Organization Group Name:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OrganizationGroup.vcr_OrganizationGroupName)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrganizationGroup.vcr_OrganizationGroupName)%>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
              Organization Group Description:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.OrganizationGroup.vcr_OrganizationGroupDesc)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OrganizationGroup.vcr_OrganizationGroupDesc)%>
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

Comment: ok strange almost the same code works for entity framework model? I created the entity model and changed just the database insert edit stuff. it works. but what wrong i may be doing above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it (might) be because your view is inheriting from `OrganizationGroupFormViewModel` and in the post of the view you are using the model `OrganizationGroup`.

I'd try accepting the OrganizationGroupFormViewModel in the post though this is untested.

**EDIT**

The other thing you might try is in your textboxes using the name that is fully qualified to your model.

```
<%= Html.textbox("model.field", model.field) %>
```

I've found this helps when I'm not passing in the form view model to my controller.

Comment: I've had the same issue with textboxfor in partial views.  not in the main view just partials and i can't explain it.  perhaps you could raise a question?

Comment: ok thanks yes for me also there is no problem in the full view